# Print the first letter of each word in a sentence

Tags: c

I am learning C programming and I am trying to print the first letter of each word in a sentence. I have written this code below but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[100];int i,l;
    scanf("%s",&s);
    l=strlen(s);
    printf("%c",s[0]);
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==' ')
        {
            printf("%c",s[i+1]);
        }
    }
 }
```

Input: Hello World

Expected Output: HW

Actual Output: (nothing)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in how you're reading the input:

```
scanf("%s",&s);
```

The `%s` format specifier to `scanf` reads characters until it encounters whitespace.  This means it stops reading at the first space.

If you want to read a full line of text, use `fgets` instead:

```
fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
```

Answer (score -1):

just Change `%s` at `scanf()` to:

```
%[^\n]
```

This makes it scans until it finds an enter.

```
scanf("%[^\n]", &inisial);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 int main()
 {
   char str1[100];
   char newString[10][10]; 
   int i,j,ctr;
   printf(" Input  a string : ");
    fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin);    
    j=0; ctr=0;
    for(i=0;i<=(strlen(str1));i++)
    {
        if(str1[i]==' '||str1[i]=='\0')
        {
             newString[ctr][j]='\0';
            ctr++;
            j=0;
        }
        else
        {
            newString[ctr][j]=str1[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i < ctr;i++)
    {

        printf(" %c\n",(newString[i])[0]);

    }
    return 0;
}
//Here is your working code
```

Comment: Care to explain what you did to the code, and why you did it?